# How to use super in python for initializing variable

Tags: python

I don't want to initialize the variable `r` and `c` again in the `GE` class.
Instead, I want to use the `__init__` method of `Employee`. How should I do it?

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,r,c):
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        print(r"Complex no =",self.r,"+",self.c,"i")
        print("")

class GE(Employee):
    def __init__(self,r,c,promotion="yes"):
        super(r,c).__init__()
        #self.promotion = "yes"
        print(self.promotion)
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), or [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+super+init)?

Comment: You need to pass `r` and `c` to the superclass's `__init__()`, not to `super()`.

Comment: Employee.__init__(self,r,c)